# How to select the bigger date between 2 columns?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table 'processes' with the following columns :

- id
- date_creation
- date_lastrun

For example I have the following entries:

```
id;date_creation;date_lastrun
1;2022-01-01 00:00:00;2022-02-01 00:00:00
2;2022-03-01 00:00:00;NULL
```

I want to select the element with the bigger date in MySQL
I can do

```
SELECT id, MAX(IFNULL(date_lastrun, date_creation)) as lastdate 
FROM processes
```

It's OK it works but now I want to get the element with the bigger date compared to a specific date time.
I tried :

```
SELECT id, MAX(IFNULL(date_lastrun, date_creation)) as lastdate 
FROM processes 
WHERE DATE(lastdate) > "2022-03-01"
```

but it returns *#1054 - Unknown column 'lastdate' in 'where clause'

```
SELECT id, MAX(IFNULL(date_lastrun, date_creation)) as lastdate 
FROM processes 
WHERE DATE(MAX(IFNULL(date_lastrun, date_creation))) > "2022-03-01"
```

but it returns *#1111 - Invalid use of group function*

Do you have any idea how to accomplish that?

I hope to return the element with the bigger date compared to a specific date.

Comment: What is your version of MySql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use the MAX in the WHERE clause but limit the result to dates bigger than "2022-03-01" and then get the biggest one.

> SELECT id, MAX(IFNULL(date_lastrun, date_creation)) as lastdate  FROM
> processes  WHERE DATE(IFNULL(date_lastrun, date_creation)) >
> "2022-03-01";

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer `GREATEST` with `COALESCE` here:

```
SELECT id, GREATEST(COALESCE(date_creation,0), COALESCE(date_lastrun,0)) AS lastdate
FROM processes
WHERE GREATEST(COALESCE(date_creation,0), COALESCE(date_lastrun,0)) > "2022-03-01";
```

`MAX` is unhandy in this situation due to its limitation to one argument, see also this article: [difference max <-> greatest](https://database.guide/max-vs-greatest-in-mysql-whats-the-difference/)

`COALESCE` is required in this case because `GREATEST` is not able to deal with `NULL` values in MYSQL.

Try out: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/VC2ioxd5)